# Swiper JS slidesOffsetBefore breakpoint param not initializing properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, swiper.js

I'm experiencing an issue with Swiper in a React component where the slidesOffsetBefore property is not being set correctly for mobile breakpoints on initial page load. The mobileLeftMargin state, which holds a pixel value (e.g., 34), is expected to be used as the slidesOffsetBefore value. However, the swiper container defaults to a slidesOffsetBefore value of 90 (which is intended for desktop), even when the page is loaded in a mobile view (e.g., width of 440px). It only applies the correct mobileLeftMargin after manually resizing the browser window to a larger size and then shrinking it back down.

Here's the relevant useEffect hook where I initialize the Swiper:

```
useEffect(() => {
        // Parameters to be passed into the initialization functions
        const swiperParams = {
            slidesPerView: 6,
            sideSlideVisiblePercent: 0.4,
            spaceBetween: 5,
        };

        // Delay the initialization to ensure DOM elements are available
        setTimeout(() => {initializeFeaturedSwiper(swiperParams);}, 200);
    }, [mobileLeftMargin]);
```

```
const initializeFeaturedSwiper = ({ slidesPerView, sideSlideVisiblePercent, spaceBetween }) => {
        const swiperContainerFeatured = document.querySelector(`#swiper1`);
        if (swiperContainerFeatured) {
            const swiperParamsFeatured = {
                slidesPerView: (slidesPerView + (sideSlideVisiblePercent * 2)) / 6,
                slidesPerGroup: 1,
                spaceBetween: spaceBetween + 6,
                speed: 400,
                navigation: true,
                slidesOffsetBefore: 90,
                slidesOffsetAfter: 90,
                injectStyles: featuredProcessedStyles,
                autoplay: {
                    delay: 5000,
                    disableOnInteraction: false,
                    pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
                },
                breakpoints: {
                    768: {
                        slidesPerView: (slidesPerView + (sideSlideVisiblePercent * 2)) / 6,
                        slidesOffsetBefore: 90,
                        slidesOffsetAfter: 90,
                        navigation: { enabled: true }
                    },
                    500: {
                        slidesPerView: (slidesPerView + (sideSlideVisiblePercent * 2)) / 6,
                        slidesOffsetBefore: 90,
                        slidesOffsetAfter: 90,
                        navigation: { enabled: false }
                    },
                    100: {
                        slidesPerView: ((slidesPerView + (sideSlideVisiblePercent * 2)) / 6) + 0.1,
                        slidesOffsetBefore: mobileLeftMargin,
                        slidesOffsetAfter: mobileLeftMargin,
                        navigation: { enabled: false }
                    }
                }
            };
            Object.assign(swiperContainerFeatured, swiperParamsFeatured);
            swiperContainerFeatured.initialize();
        }
    };
```

I've explored numerous forums, attempted using the observer and observeParents options, setting init='false' inline in the swiper-container, and I tried setting the mobile slidesOffsetBefore as the default for the swiper container, but none have resolved the issue. The swiper container correctly applies the mobile breakpoint only after resizing. How can I ensure that Swiper applies the correct breakpoint settings on initial page load for mobile views?